# s3cmd fails to run from an init-script

Tags: debian, init-script, s3cmd

I created an init-script that should push some log files using `s3cmd` to an Amazon S3 bucket when the system is going down. [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) is installed and `s3cmd --configure` was run as user `root` and the configuration is OK

When manually executing the init script, it does the job but when it is executed by `init` during a shutdown, it fails.

What can be the reason? What is different when the init-script is run by `init`? Maybe it cannot read the `/root/.s3cfg` file?

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

The assumption about `s3cmd` not being able to read its config file was right. For some reason unknown to me, during runlevel change (0), when `init` executes init-scripts, apparently the `root` user who does run those scripts doesn't count as a "real" user so it doesn't have a "home" directory from where `s3cmd` tries to read the config.

Explicitly specifying the config file's location using the `--config=...` solves this problem.

Comment: Well spotted, +1.